# Wear OS, Android: disable or close Quick Panel

Tags: android, wear-os, samsung

I'm trying to find a way to disable or to close the Quick Panel with my app to limit the ability to switch modes on devices. My device is Samsung Galaxy Watch 4 (SM-R860).

With next the command:

```
adb.exe shell "dumpsys activity broadcasts |grep -iE ".+\.[0-9A-Z_\-]+:$" |sort"
```

I was able to get a list of intents, and the following lines can be found in it:

```
        com.google.android.apps.wearable.systemui.CLOSE_QUICK_PANEL:
        com.google.android.apps.wearable.systemui.DISABLE_EXPAND_QUICK_PANEL:
        com.google.android.apps.wearable.systemui.ENABLE_EXPAND_QUICK_PANEL:
        com.google.android.apps.wearable.systemui.OPEN_QUICK_PANEL:
        com.google.android.apps.wearable.systemui.QUICK_PANEL_STATE_CLOSED:
        com.google.android.apps.wearable.systemui.QUICK_PANEL_STATE_OPENED:
```

I see that it is possible to disable and to close the panel, but how can I implement it from my application?

Comment: Denis did you solved it and how? I have a similar question can you help [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73054453/wearos-3-hide-swipe-top-guesture-for-quick-settings-panel-and-use-navigation-dr),  please?

Comment: @RedCoder the problem was solved by itself after the next update from Samsung (Build: R860XXU1FVC8/R860OXM1FVC8, One UI Watch 4). It is likely that for other devices the problem remains.

Comment: This problem persists in WearOs4.0. I am looking for a way to disable the quick panel after  latest update of Samsung watches to WearOS4.0