# WearOS 3 Hide swipe top guesture, for Quick Settings Panel and use Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0, android-wear-3.0

I find out about this problem for my users with the new Wear OS 3.
I am trying to forbid to OS from detecting the Top swipe gesture for showing the **"*System Quick settings panel*"**.
Until now in Wear OS 2- devices, it's not allowed to open this system shortcut settings Panel into a custom app.

**"*System Quick settings panel*"**:

[image: System Quick settings]

I currently detect swipe from the top gesture (via NavigationDrawer) and show the 'logging out' fragment.

[image]

```
 private void initNavigationDrawer() {
    List<NavigationItem> navigationItems = new ArrayList<>();
    navigationItems.add(new NavigationItem(getString(R.string.logout_button), getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_bsh_play_icon)));
    binding.navigationDrawer.setAdapter(new NavigationAdapter(navigationItems));
    binding.navigationDrawer.getController().peekDrawer();
    binding.navigationDrawer.addOnItemSelectedListener(pos -> {
        if (navigationItems.get(pos).getItemTitle().equals(getString(R.string.logout_button))) {
            mainViewModel.logout();
        }
    });
}
```

NavigationAdapter:

```
public class NavigationAdapter extends WearableNavigationDrawerView.WearableNavigationDrawerAdapter {

  private final List<NavigationItem> items;

  NavigationAdapter(List<NavigationItem> items) {
    this.items = items;
  }

  @Override
  public CharSequence getItemText(int pos) {
    return items.get(pos).getItemTitle();
  }

  @Override
  public Drawable getItemDrawable(int pos) {
    return items.get(pos).getItemIcon();
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance!!

P.C I found one similar question, with some guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71741160/wear-os-android-disable-or-close-quick-panel)

Comment: You've linked to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try "Lock task mode" described [here](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode). I don't know if this solution meets your requirements, but for my application it was enough to change the AndroidManifest.xml. For your activity, add the line android:lockTaskMode with the value "always".
For example:

```
...
     <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:lockTaskMode="always"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:theme="@style/YourTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
...
```

Add your style based on the existing one. Here is my added style file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="YourTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowSwipeToDismiss">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

You can also provide an exit from your application by intercepting button presses on the device body, or by adding a button on the user interface.

Comment: Thank you very much, Denis. It helped by not showing the settings screen but crashed the whole Watch... I should restart the watch... Is there a way to fix that

Comment: @RedCoder did you solve your problem?

Comment: nope, i couldn't solve it without to bug up whole watch :D

Comment: how can i make that lock safer and clear way